# Event-handling in actionscript

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to learn event-handling methods in AS2.
Can you please recommend me good website for learning?(a free one is good)

Answer (score 0):

From google:

http://flash-creations.com/notes/actionscript_eventhandlers.php

ian.